# Are questions about any distros based on Ubuntu on topic? (Made using tools like Distroshare Ubuntu Imager)

Tags: discussion, scope

There are some tools on internet like [Distroshare Ubuntu Imager](https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager) to make distributions based on Ubuntu. Are questions on those distributions on topic here? Or are they off topic?

Assume that someone installed fresh Ubuntu. They he customized it by installing packages, from Ubuntu repositories and by compiling from source. Then he set his own distribution name and code. But he kept default Ubuntu repositories for APT Then he released it using those tools. Then I downloaded that. Then can I ask about that as that distro uses official Ubuntu repositories? Or are they off topic and I should ask them on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange?

Comment: As per the [custom-distributions tag](https://askubuntu.com/tags/custom-distributions/info): "Questions about creating (*not using*) a custom-built version of Ubuntu."